# Multivariable limit with parameter: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{yx^n}{x^6+y^2} \forall n\ge4$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve a limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(yx^n)}{(x^6+y^2 )} \forall n\ge4$$ 
 I don't know how can i start to solve it, can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: $$\left\| \dfrac{yx^n}{x^6+y^2}\right\|\le \left\| \dfrac{yx^n}{x^6}\right\|=\left\| yx^{n-6}\right\|,$$ so for $n\ge 6$ the limit is equal to $0$. You need to check $n=4,5$.

Comment: sorry, i'm not getting it. are you using that if f<g then lim f < lim g ?

Comment: Kind of. You can see it as an application of the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is equivalent to $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{ix^N}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^3 +iy}-\frac{1}{x^3 -iy}\bigg)$$ which is dominated by the terms $x^{N-3} - x^{N-3}$. For $N>3$ it seems to me that this would go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Putting either limt of x or y as 0 makes the limit 0 i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(yx^n)}{(x^6+y^2 )}= \lim_{y\to0} \frac{(yx^n)}{(x^6+y^2 )}=0$$

Comment: But that is sufficient to say that the limit exists for all n?

Answer (score 0):

For all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, this inequality holds by AM-GM inequality:
$$x^6+y^2 \ge 2 |x^3y|$$
Since $n\ge 4$,
$$0\le \left|\frac{yx^n}{x^6+y^2}\right|\le \left|\frac{yx^n}{2x^3y}\right|=\frac{1}{2}|x|^{n-3}$$
and $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|x|^{n-3}=0.$ Therefore,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{yx^n}{x^6+y^2}=0.$$